# How to create a proper inheritance with dependencies?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, dependencies, abstraction

While working on my Unity project, I created an abstract class and stored a to reference it as a field. I then called its function `Init` on `Start` in order to pass to it its needed references.

So let's say I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Base : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected BaseTool _baseTool; // A references that every inheritor uses
    
    public virtual void Init(BaseTool baseTool)
    {
        _baseTool = baseTool;
    }

    ... // More functuality
}
```

Now I store it as a field as below:

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Base _base;

    [SerializeField]
    BaseTool _baseTool;

    void Start()
    {
        _base.Init(_baseTool);
    }
}
```

And now I have an inheritor:

```
public class Inheritor1 : Base 
{
    public override Init(BaseTool baseTool)
    {
        base.Init(baseTool);
    }

    ... // More functuality
}
```

So far everything is good. However, let's say I now have another inheritor which also has a dependency on another tool:

```
public class Inheritor2 : Base 
{
    private Inheritor2Tool _inheritor2Tool; // The dependency
}
```

That means, that if I want to override `Init` with `Inheritor2` (so I'll be able to call `Init` in `Foo` and initialize whatever inheritor is stored inside the field `_base`) I'll need to change the whole `Init` signature to `Init(BaseTool baseTool, Inheritor2Tool inheritor2Tool)` meanwhile only `Inheritor2` will use the new parameter `Inheritor2Tool inheritor2Tool`.

That seems very wrong to me, but I don't know how I can avoid this.
So what are my options?

Comment: seems to me that your goal is somewhat unclear... i think you have some form of IoC container in mind ... does this point in your direction? ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgBmAkkLFBI

Comment: Solutions belong in the answer space below. Do not edit the question with the solution